# Constrain multiple sliderInput in shiny to sum to 100

Tags: r, shiny

I've been struggling with this all day and I've kind of solved it (horrible hack). However there experience is not smooth and displays side-effects.

What I want is three sliders with a range of 0 to 100 constrained such that their sum should always be 100.

This is a screenshot of what it looks like[image: Screenshot]

Here's the server.R shiny code.

```
library(shiny)

oldState<-NULL
newState<-NULL

getState<-function(input) c(input$slider1, input$slider2, input$slider3)

# Define server logic required
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    newState<<-getState(input)
    i<-which(oldState-newState != 0)[1]
    if(!is.na(i)){
      rem <- 100-newState[i]
      a<-sum(newState[-i])
      if(a==0) newState[-i]<<-rem/length(newState[-i])
      else newState[-i]<<-rem*(newState[-i]/a)
      for(j in 1:length(newState))
        if(j!=i)
          updateSliderInput(session, paste0("slider", j), value=newState[j])
    }
    oldState<<-newState
  })

  output$restable <- renderTable({
    myvals<-getState(input)
    myvals<-c(myvals, sum(myvals))
    data.frame(Names=c("Slider 1", "Slider 2", "Slider 3", "Sum"),
               Values=myvals)
  })
})
```

and here is the ui.R shiny code

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("Sliders should sum to 100!"),

  # Sidebar with sliders whos sum should be constrained to be 100
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("slider1", "Slider 1: ", min = 0, max = 100, value = 40, step=1),
    sliderInput("slider2", "Slider 2: ", min = 0, max = 100, value = 30, step=1),
    sliderInput("slider3", "Slider 3: ", min = 0, max = 100, value = 30, step=1)
  ),

  # Create table output
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("restable")
  )
))
```

Now this does pretty much what it should except two things:

- It feels like a hack i.e. there should be a better way of doing this
- When I move a slider into a position it sometimes jumps to a slightly lower or higher position. I have no idea why.

How do I fix these two issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this thread while trying to implement the same thing. I've worked out a solution motivated by the pseudo-code laid out by bmc above and thought I'd share.

I use three different `observeEvent()` calls to force the other two sliders to adjust when one of the sliders change. When (automatically) adjusting the other two sliders, I force their ratio to be the same as prior to the event while ensuring they sum to the remainder left after the user manually adjusts one slider.

This is demonstrated below using an interactive Rmarkdown document, but this should transfer to standard shiny apps as well.

````
---
title: "Force Sliders to Sum to 100"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(shiny)
```

```{r inputs}
sliderInput("s1", "Slider 1", min = 0, max = 100, value = 50, step = 0.1)
sliderInput("s2", "Slider 2", min = 0, max = 100, value = 25, step = 0.1)
sliderInput("s3", "Slider 3", min = 0, max = 100, value = 25, step = 0.1)

# when s1 changes, adjust other two to fill the remainder with the same ratio as they currently have
observeEvent(input$s1, {
  remaining <- 100 - input$s1
  p_remaining_s2 <- input$s2/(input$s2 + input$s3)
  p_remaining_s3 <- input$s3/(input$s2 + input$s3)
  updateSliderInput(inputId = "s2", value = remaining * p_remaining_s2)
  updateSliderInput(inputId = "s3", value = remaining * p_remaining_s3)
})

# when s2 changes, do the same
observeEvent(input$s2, {
  remaining <- 100 - input$s2
  p_remaining_s1 <- input$s1/(input$s1 + input$s3)
  p_remaining_s3 <- input$s3/(input$s1 + input$s3)
  updateSliderInput(inputId = "s1", value = remaining * p_remaining_s1)
  updateSliderInput(inputId = "s3", value = remaining * p_remaining_s3)
})

# when s3 changes, do the same
observeEvent(input$s3, {
  remaining <- 100 - input$s3
  p_remaining_s1 <- input$s1/(input$s1 + input$s2)
  p_remaining_s2 <- input$s2/(input$s1 + input$s2)
  updateSliderInput(inputId = "s1", value = remaining * p_remaining_s1)
  updateSliderInput(inputId = "s2", value = remaining * p_remaining_s2)
})
```

```{r outputs}
renderTable({
  data.frame(
    Slider = c("1", "2", "3", "sum"), 
    Value = c(input$s1, input$s2, input$s3, input$s1 + input$s2 + input$s3)
  )
})
```
````

Answer (score 4):

I think using [dynamicUI](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#dynamic-ui) might solve your problem.

If you know that there need to be exactly 3 inputs that sum to 1, then you can restrict your user to just two slider inputs and make the 2nd slider input contingent on the first, as follows. Using your code template:

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$slider2 <- renderUI {
    sliderInput("slider2", "Slider 2", min = 0,  max = 100 - input$slider1, value = 0)  
  })

  output$restable <- renderTable({
    myvals<- c(input$slider1, input$slider2, 100-input$slider1-input$slider2)
    data.frame(Names=c("Slider 1", "Slider 2", "Slider 3"),
               Values=myvals)
  })
})
```

The key here is the `renderUI` function which looks up the `input$slider1` value to constrain the value of `slider2` (and hence `slider3`)

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("Sliders should sum to 100!"),

  # Sidebar with sliders whos sum should be constrained to be 100
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("slider1", "Slider 1: ", min = 0, max = 100, value = 0, step=1),
    uiOutput("slider2")
  ),

  # Create table output
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("restable")
  )
))
```

As seen (if you squint) in the attached image, `slider2` is restricted to 0-35, once `slider1` has been set at 65.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Looks promising. I should look more into the reactiveUI interface. The thing is that the specifications require that all three  sliders are present. Also Slider 2 should not be restricted to 35, but if the user goes past 35 then slider 1 and slider 3 should decrease such that the total sum remains 100.

Comment: In your example, I was confused by how *both* other sliders could change when only the third slider was manipulated. After all, there are 2 degrees of freedom (x3 = 100 - x1 - x2) and you have to collect two inputs to determine the thrid.

Comment: It's a usability feature. If you have three media channels and you want to set one of them to 80% you should be able to do that by only moving one. The other two should share the remaining 20% with the same ratio as they had before. :) This example is extremely common in interactive dashboarding solutions in Marketing.

Comment: Hi Mike, this is a brilliant question. I also face the same issue (and the number of sliders is variable for me: going from 2 to n=100+ depending on users'inputs). Would it be possible for you to share any solution/improvement you may have found ? I can't solve this efficiently either, except with a 'complex' code/script but I am looking for an elegant solution...

Comment: @user1431694 unfortunately I haven't solved it yet. I'm still struggeling. Probably due to my lack of experience with the Shiny framework. I'll keep you posted and write an answer if and when I solve it.

Comment: I am also working on it. It's tricky. I'll keep you posted as well! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

All these thoughts are helpful, but my instinct is to use the `tagList`. The algorithm runs thus,

1. Keep all sliders in a tag list
2. Let n be the length of the tag list
3. Populate all slider widgets from the tag list
4. If a slider widget changes (in the server) under `observe {...}` , identify which widget.
5. Let x be 100 minus the value of the widget changed from the tag list (3) and (4).
6. Set the value property of the remaining sliders in the tag list to `x/(n-1)`.

Hope this helps. Will update with code as soon as possible.