# Constrain two sliderInput in shiny to sum to 100

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create a shiny app with two slideinputs that add up to 100. That means, if the user changes the value of one slider, the other slider changes automatically to fulfill the constraint (100-input$slider1).

I found a similar question here:
[Examplecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952333/constrain-multiple-sliderinput-in-shiny-to-sum-to-100)

with the following code:

**Server:**

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$slider2 <- reactiveUI(function() {
    sliderInput("slider2", "Slider 2", min = 0,  max = 100 - input$slider1, value = 0)  
  })

  output$restable <- renderTable({
    myvals<- c(input$slider1, input$slider2, 100-input$slider1-input$slider2)
    data.frame(Names=c("Slider 1", "Slider 2", "Slider 3"),
               Values=myvals)
  })
})
```

**UI:**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("Sliders should sum to 100!"),

  # Sidebar with sliders whos sum should be constrained to be 100
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("slider1", "Slider 1: ", min = 0, max = 100, value = 0, step=1),
    uiOutput("slider2")
  ),

  # Create table output
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("restable")
  )
))
```

This is already a solution which is okay. But here one can only change slider 1 to get an automatical change of slider 2. On the other hand, if the user changes slider 2 then slider 1 doesn't fit to the constraint.
How can I make it posiible that one can change both sliders so that the other one fits to the constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added a double `updateSliderInput` along with `renderUI` for the second one

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui <-pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("Sliders should sum to 100!"),
  # Sidebar with sliders whos sum should be constrained to be 100
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("slider1", "Slider 1: ", min = 0, max = 100, value = 0, step=1),
    uiOutput("slider")),

  # Create table output
  mainPanel(tableOutput("restable"))
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  observe({
    updateSliderInput(session, "slider1", min =0,max=100, value = 100 - input$slider2)
  })
  output$slider <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("slider2", "Slider 2: ", min=0,max=100, value=100 - input$slider1)
  })

  output$restable <- renderTable({
    myvals<- c(input$slider1, input$slider2, 100-input$slider1-input$slider2)
    data.frame(Names=c("Slider 1", "Slider 2", "Slider 3"),Values=myvals)
  })
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it also possible to keep the max value at 100 (to see the full range from 1 to 100)?

Comment: Problem now is, if you shrink one slider you can not make it larger again afterwards

Comment: Instead of setting the max, you could directly set the value of the other slider. E.g., `updateSliderInput(session, "slider2", value = 100 - input$slider1)` Note that you need to start them summing to 100 or they will keep toggling back and forth. (I just suggested an edit to do that)

Comment: I didnt look at the edit by @MarkPeterson at the end, but I changed it to use `renderUI` instead

Comment: Yeah I have it. Thank you both

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same problem but with four sliders and run into some problems, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330299/probabilistic-multiple-choice-test-sliderinputs-sum-to-1-constraint)