# probabilistic multiple choice test, sliderInputs sum to 1 constraint

Tags: r, shiny

I'm developing a small [shinyapp](https://jtufto.shinyapps.io/testapp/) for conducting probabilistic multiple choice tests, see [Bernardo, 1997](http://www.uv.es/~bernardo/MultipleChoice.pdf).  For each question in the test, there will be say 4 possible answers.  Each participant should assign som values to each alternative reflecting their degree of belief that each alternative is the correct answer.  I'm recording this input using the `sliderInput` function.  Since the four probabilites must sum to 1, I rescale all four probabilites of the current question (a row in a matrix stored as `prob <- reactiveValues( )`) to meet this constraint.  This is triggered by `observeEvent(input$p1, )` etc.

Once these probabilities changes this triggers changes in the four `sliderInput` put inside `renderUI( )` inside the server function such that all sliders are updated.  This in turn triggers further calls to the function updating `prob` but since the probabilities at this point already sum to 1, `prob` remain unchanged so no further changes to the sliders should occur.  You can see for yourself by running the app hosted on shinyapps.io.

This usually works very well, except that in some quite rare cases an infinite loop is set off such that all four sliders keep changing forever. I believe this happens if the user makes a second change to one of the sliders before the three other sliders have had time to adjust.

So my question is really if there is some way of avoiding this loop or if there is some better way of implementing the above idea.  I noticed that there is also a `updateSliderInput` function but I don't really see how this might help solve the problem.

Update: I believe the [solution to a similar question involving just two sliders proposed in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372906/constrain-two-sliderinput-in-shiny-to-sum-to-100?rq=1) suffers from the same problem due to the mutual dependency between `slider1` and `slider2`.

```
library(shiny)
digits=3
step <- .1^digits

# Dummy questions and alternatives
n <- 5

# Miscellaneous functions
updateprob <- function(oldprobs, new, i) {
  cat(oldprobs, new, i)
  if (new==oldprobs[i]) {
    cat("-\n")
    oldprobs 
  } else {
    newprobs <- rep(0,4)
    oldprobs <- oldprobs + 1e-6 # hack to avoid 0/0 = NaN in special cases
    newprobs[-i] <- round(oldprobs[-i]/sum(oldprobs[-i])*(1-new),digits=digits)
    newprobs[i] <- new
    cat("*\n")
    newprobs
  }
}
# wrapper function around sliderInput
probsliderInput <- function(inputId,value,submitted=FALSE) {
  if (!submitted)
    sliderInput(inputId=inputId,
                value=value,
                label=NULL,
                min=0,
                max=1,
                step=step,
                round=-digits,
                ticks=FALSE)
}

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Initialize the quiz here, possibly permute the quiz
  prob <- reactiveValues(prob=matrix(rep(.25,4*n),n,4)) # current choice of probabilities
  question <- reactiveValues(i=1) # question number

  # Actions to take if pressing next and previous buttons
  observeEvent(input$nextquestion,{question$i <- min(question$i+1,n)}) 
  observeEvent(input$previousquestion,{question$i <- max(question$i-1,1)}) 

  # If any of the probability sliders change, then recalculate probabilities to satisfy sum to 1 constraint
  observeEvent(input$p1, 
               prob$prob[question$i,] <- updateprob(prob$prob[question$i,], input$p1, 1)
  )
  observeEvent(input$p2, 
               prob$prob[question$i,] <- updateprob(prob$prob[question$i,], input$p2, 2)
  )
  observeEvent(input$p3, 
               prob$prob[question$i,] <- updateprob(prob$prob[question$i,], input$p3, 3)
  )
  observeEvent(input$p4, 
               prob$prob[question$i,] <- updateprob(prob$prob[question$i,], input$p4, 4)
  )

  # If the probabilities change, update the sliders
  output$p1ui <- renderUI({
    probsliderInput("p1",prob$prob[question$i,1])
  })
  output$p2ui <- renderUI({
    probsliderInput("p2",prob$prob[question$i,2])
  })
  output$p3ui <- renderUI({
    probsliderInput("p3",prob$prob[question$i,3])
  })
  output$p4ui <- renderUI({
    probsliderInput("p4",prob$prob[question$i,4])
  })

  # Render the buttons sometimes greyed out
  output$previousbutton <- renderUI({
    actionButton("previousquestion",icon=icon("angle-left"),label="Previous",
                 style=if (question$i > 1) "color: #000" else "color: #aaa")
  })
  output$nextbutton <- renderUI({
    actionButton("nextquestion",icon=icon("angle-right"),label="Next",
                 style=if (question$i < n) "color: #000" else "color: #aaa")
  })

  # Current question number
  output$number <- renderText(paste("Question",question$i))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("previousbutton", inline = TRUE),
  uiOutput("nextbutton", inline = TRUE),
  textOutput("number"),
  uiOutput("p1ui"),
  uiOutput("p2ui"),
  uiOutput("p3ui"),
  uiOutput("p4ui")
)

shinyApp(ui=ui , server=server)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can `suspend()` the sliders until everything is recalculated and `resume()` them afterwards:

```
library(shiny)
digits=3
step <- .1^digits

# Dummy questions and alternatives
n <- 5

# Miscellaneous functions
updateprob <- function(oldprobs, new, i) {
    cat(oldprobs, new, i)
    if (new==oldprobs[i]) {
        cat("-\n")
        oldprobs
    } else {
        newprobs <- rep(0,4)
        oldprobs <- oldprobs + 1e-6 # hack to avoid 0/0 = NaN in special cases
        newprobs[-i] <- round(oldprobs[-i]/sum(oldprobs[-i])*(1-new),digits=digits)
        newprobs[i] <- new
        cat("*\n")
        newprobs
    }
}

# new functions to suspend and resume a list of observers
suspendMany <- function(observers) invisible(lapply(observers, function(o) o$suspend()))
resumeMany <- function(observers) invisible(lapply(observers, function(o) o$resume()))

# wrapper function around sliderInput
probsliderInput <- function(inputId,value,submitted=FALSE) {
    if (!submitted)
        sliderInput(inputId=inputId,
                    value=value,
                    label=NULL,
                    min=0,
                    max=1,
                    step=step,
                    round=-digits,
                    ticks=FALSE)
}

server <- function(input, output) {
    # Initialize the quiz here, possibly permute the quiz
    prob <- reactiveValues(prob=matrix(rep(.25,4*n),n,4),
                           ready = F) # current choice of probabilities

    question <- reactiveValues(i=1) # question number



    # Actions to take if pressing next and previous buttons
    observeEvent(input$nextquestion,{question$i <- min(question$i+1,n)})
    observeEvent(input$previousquestion,{question$i <- max(question$i-1,1)})

    # If any of the probability sliders change, then recalculate probabilities to satisfy sum to 1 constraint
    # We put all observers in a list to handle them conveniently
    observers <- list(
    observeEvent(input$p1,
                 {
                   suspendMany(observers)
                   prob$prob[question$i,] <- updateprob(prob$prob[question$i,], input$p1, 1)
                   resumeMany(observers)
                 }
    ),
    observeEvent(input$p2,
                 {
                   suspendMany(observers)
                   prob$prob[question$i,] <- updateprob(prob$prob[question$i,], input$p2, 2)
                   resumeMany(observers)
                 }
    ),
    observeEvent(input$p3,
                 {
                   suspendMany(observers)
                   prob$prob[question$i,] <- updateprob(prob$prob[question$i,], input$p3, 3)
                   resumeMany(observers)
                 }
    ),
    observeEvent(input$p4,
                 {
                   suspendMany(observers)
                   prob$prob[question$i,] <- updateprob(prob$prob[question$i,], input$p4, 4)
                   resumeMany(observers)
                 }
    )
    )

    # If the probabilities change, update the sliders
    output$p1ui <- renderUI({
        probsliderInput("p1",prob$prob[question$i,1])
    })
    output$p2ui <- renderUI({
        probsliderInput("p2",prob$prob[question$i,2])
    })
    output$p3ui <- renderUI({
        probsliderInput("p3",prob$prob[question$i,3])
    })
    output$p4ui <- renderUI({
        probsliderInput("p4",prob$prob[question$i,4])
    })

    # Render the buttons sometimes greyed out
    output$previousbutton <- renderUI({
        actionButton("previousquestion",icon=icon("angle-left"),label="Previous",
                     style=if (question$i > 1) "color: #000" else "color: #aaa")
    })
    output$nextbutton <- renderUI({
        actionButton("nextquestion",icon=icon("angle-right"),label="Next",
                     style=if (question$i < n) "color: #000" else "color: #aaa")
    })

    # Current question number
    output$number <- renderText(paste("Question",question$i))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("previousbutton", inline = TRUE),
    uiOutput("nextbutton", inline = TRUE),
    textOutput("number"),
    uiOutput("p1ui"),
    uiOutput("p2ui"),
    uiOutput("p3ui"),
    uiOutput("p4ui")
)

shinyApp(ui=ui , server=server)
```

Comment: Really nice solution

Answer (score 3):

The problem you describes comes from a observer loop triggered when `updateprob` is called. As @AEF is saying you can either suspend the observers in your server.R code or you can disable the event propagation using Javascript.

I see that you do a lot of manually defining sliders in your server.R code so here's a answer where the number of questions and number of sliders are dynamic:

```
library(shiny)
digits=3
step <- .1^digits

# Dummy questions and alternatives
num.questions <- 6
num.sliders   <- sample(2:8, num.questions) # Change to, rep(n, num.questions) for same amount of sliders

# Helper function to calculate new values for sliders
updateprob <- function(oldprobs, new, i) {
  oldprobs <- oldprobs + 1e-6 # hack to avoid 0/0 = NaN in special cases
  ret        <- rep(0,length(oldprobs))
  ind.other  <- c(1:length(oldprobs))[! 1:length(oldprobs) %in% i]
  sum.others <- sum( oldprobs[ind.other] )
  range.left <- 1 - new
  ret[i]     <- new
  for( n in ind.other ){
    ret[n] <- ( oldprobs[n] * range.left) /sum.others
  }
  return(ret)
}

# wrapper function around sliderInput
probsliderInput <- function(inputId,value,submitted=FALSE) {
  if (!submitted)
    sliderInput(inputId=inputId,
                value=value,
                label=NULL,
                min=0,
                max=1,
                step=step,
                round=-digits,
                ticks=FALSE)
}

# Helper function, generates HTML for all sliders
generateSliders <- function(id, n){
  sliders <- lapply(1:n, function(i){
    probsliderInput(sprintf("q%ss%d",id,i),1/n)
  })
  do.call(fluidRow, sliders)
}

# Generate observers for all sliders and bind a callback to them
generateObservers <- function(id, n, input, session, callback){
  lapply(1:n,function(i){
    c.id <- sprintf("q%ss%d",id, i)
    print(sprintf("Observer for slider with id %s generated",c.id))
    observeEvent(input[[ sprintf("q%ss%d",id, i) ]],{
      do.call( callback, list(id, n, i, input, session) )
    })
  })
}

getSlidersValues <- function(id, n, input){ # Get all slider values
  unlist(lapply(1:n,function(i){
    input[[sprintf("q%ss%d",id,i)]]
  }))
}

setSliderValues <-function(id, ns, session, new.vals){ # Set all slider values
  suspendMany(observers)
  for(i in 1:ns){
    local({
      il <- i
      updateSliderInput( session, sprintf("q%ss%d",id,il),value=new.vals[il]) 
    })
  }
  resumeMany(observers)
}

# Callbackfunction for all sliders, triggers the change of all slider values
normalizeSliders <- function(id, nt, nc, input, session){
  print(sprintf("[q%ss%d] Slider %d moved, total: %d, l: %d",id,nc,nc, nt,length(observers)))

  vals     <- getSlidersValues(id, nt, input)
  new.vals <- updateprob(vals, input[[sprintf("q%ss%d",id, nc)]],nc)

  # Not necessary to suspend observers but helps in reducing number of function calls
  suspendMany(observers)
  for(i in 1:nt){
    updateSliderInput( session, sprintf("q%ss%d",id,i),value=new.vals[i]) 
  }
  resumeMany(observers)
}

# Thanks to @AEF
suspendMany <- function(observers) invisible(lapply(observers, function(o) o$suspend()))
resumeMany  <- function(observers) invisible(lapply(observers, function(o) o$resume()))

initiateProbs <- function(ns){
  lapply(ns,function(i){
    rep( 1/i, i) 
  })
}


# server.R
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # matrix(rep(1/num.sliders,num.sliders*num.questions),num.questions,num.sliders)
  prob <- reactiveValues( prob= initiateProbs(num.sliders) )
  observers <- NULL

  observeEvent(input$questionNum, {
    q.num <- as.character( input$questionNum )
    cns   <- num.sliders[[input$questionNum]]

    sliders   <- generateSliders( q.num, cns ) # Generate sliders
    observers <<- generateObservers( q.num, cns, input, session, normalizeSliders) # Generate observers and bind callbacks to all sliders

    output$sliders <- renderUI({ sliders })
  })

  # ------ Toggle question observers --------
  observeEvent(input$previousquestion,{ 
    cns <- num.sliders[[input$questionNum]]
    if (input$questionNum <= 1) return()
    prob$prob[[input$questionNum]] <- getSlidersValues( as.character( input$questionNum ), cns ,input) # Save probability matrix
    updateNumericInput(session, "questionNum", value=input$questionNum-1) # Update hidden question counter field
  })
  observeEvent(input$nextquestion,{ 
    cns <- num.sliders[[input$questionNum]]
    if (input$questionNum  >= num.questions) return()
    prob$prob[[input$questionNum]] <- getSlidersValues( as.character( input$questionNum ), cns,input)  # Save probability matrix
    updateNumericInput(session, "questionNum", value=input$questionNum+1) # Update hidden question counter field
  })

  # Triggered on changing question number
  observeEvent(input$questionNum,{
    # Not necessary to suspend observers but helps in reducing number of function calls
    suspendMany(observers)
    setSliderValues( as.character( input$questionNum ), num.sliders[[input$questionNum]], session,  prob$prob[[input$questionNum]]) # Update sliders from probability matrix
    resumeMany(observers)
  })

  output$number  <- renderText(paste("Question", input$questionNum)) # Show question number
}

# ui.R
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("previousquestion",icon=icon("angle-left"),label="Previous",
               style="color: #000"),
  actionButton("nextquestion",icon=icon("angle-right"),label="Next",
               style="#000"),
  uiOutput("nextbutton", inline = TRUE),
  textOutput("number"),
  uiOutput('sliders'),
  div(numericInput('questionNum','Hidden',1), style="visibility: hidden;")
)

shinyApp(ui=ui , server=server)
```

Here I'm simply first looping to create the actual HTML elements, then I'm assigning observers to them. The observers have a callback function which is called each time the observer fires.

Comment: This is excellent!  Works like a charm.  And I certainly agree that manually defining sliders is bad idea.

Comment: Well, I guess it depends, maybe it's to much work if the number of sliders are constant for all questions but with this setup you could easily vary the number of sliders per question. Is this something your trying to do?

Comment: It's a possibility to consider, yes.  In anycase it makes the code more consise and easier to develop further.  Maybe I'll post a version containing a real quiz at some point.

Comment: But doesn't `observers` need to be defined locally within the server function such that it becomes specific to each session initiated by different users?  Otherwise, wouldn't there be a potential conflict between concurrent sessions belonging to different users?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to have a dynamic number of sliders for each question. And yes, good catch!, the observers need to be defined inside the scope of server.R and not as a global variable for all session. http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html

Answer (score 0):

(I think) I managed to fix the infinite loop of readjusting by adding an actionButton for each slider. Now the user adjusts a slider, and then hits the appropriate recalculate button at which point the sliders update, instead of the sliders constantly trying to update themselves.

Having the four buttons isn't the prettiest and there might be a way to make it clearer what the user has to do, but all the functionality is there.

```
library(shiny)
digits=3
step <- .1^digits

# Dummy questions and alternatives
n <- 5

# Miscellaneous functions
updateprob <- function(oldprobs, new, i) {
  cat(oldprobs, new, i)
  if (new==oldprobs[i]) {
    cat("-\n")
    oldprobs 
  } else {
    newprobs <- rep(0,4)
    oldprobs <- oldprobs + 1e-6 # hack to avoid 0/0 = NaN in special cases
    newprobs[-i] <- round(oldprobs[-i]/sum(oldprobs[-i])*(1-new),digits=digits)
    newprobs[i] <- new
    cat("*\n")
    newprobs
  }
}
# wrapper function around sliderInput
probsliderInput <- function(inputId,value,submitted=FALSE) {
  if (!submitted)
    sliderInput(inputId=inputId,
                value=value,
                label=NULL,
                min=0,
                max=1,
                step=step,
                round=-digits,
                ticks=FALSE)
}

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Initialize the quiz here, possibly permute the quiz
  prob <- reactiveValues(prob=matrix(rep(.25,4*n),n,4)) # current choice of probabilities
  question <- reactiveValues(i=1) # question number

  # Actions to take if pressing next and previous buttons
  observeEvent(input$nextquestion,{question$i <- min(question$i+1,n)}) 
  observeEvent(input$previousquestion,{question$i <- max(question$i-1,1)}) 

  # If the user presses the actionButton, then recalculate probabilities to satisfy sum to 1 constraint
  observeEvent(input$recalc1, 
               prob$prob[question$i,] <- updateprob(prob$prob[question$i,], input$p1, 1)
  )
  observeEvent(input$recalc2, 
               prob$prob[question$i,] <- updateprob(prob$prob[question$i,], input$p2, 2)
  )
  observeEvent(input$recalc3, 
               prob$prob[question$i,] <- updateprob(prob$prob[question$i,], input$p3, 3)
  )
  observeEvent(input$recalc4, 
               prob$prob[question$i,] <- updateprob(prob$prob[question$i,], input$p4, 4)
  )

  # If the probabilities change, update the sliders
  output$p1ui <- renderUI({
    probsliderInput("p1",prob$prob[question$i,1])
  })
  output$p2ui <- renderUI({
    probsliderInput("p2",prob$prob[question$i,2])
  })
  output$p3ui <- renderUI({
    probsliderInput("p3",prob$prob[question$i,3])
  })
  output$p4ui <- renderUI({
    probsliderInput("p4",prob$prob[question$i,4])
  })

  # Render the buttons sometimes greyed out
  output$previousbutton <- renderUI({
    actionButton("previousquestion",icon=icon("angle-left"),label="Previous",
                 style=if (question$i > 1) "color: #000" else "color: #aaa")
  })
  output$nextbutton <- renderUI({
    actionButton("nextquestion",icon=icon("angle-right"),label="Next",
                 style=if (question$i < n) "color: #000" else "color: #aaa")
  })

  # Current question number
  output$number <- renderText(paste("Question",question$i))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("previousbutton", inline = TRUE),
  uiOutput("nextbutton", inline = TRUE),
  textOutput("number"),
  uiOutput("p1ui"),
  actionButton(inputId = "recalc1", label = "Recalculate sliders"),
  uiOutput("p2ui"),
  actionButton(inputId = "recalc2", label = "Recalculate sliders"),
  uiOutput("p3ui"),
  actionButton(inputId = "recalc3", label = "Recalculate sliders"),
  uiOutput("p4ui"),
  actionButton(inputId = "recalc4", label = "Recalculate sliders")
)

shinyApp(ui=ui , server=server)
```

Comment: Yes, I suppose something along these lines might be more stable.  What I want if say slider 4 is changed to some new value p4 is to scale the remaining probabilities p1, p2, p3 such that these sum to 1 - p4 while keeping p4 unchanged at its new value.

Comment: I've updated the solution so it now works like that. It's not perfect from a layout/usability perspective, but I gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

This is one option. Update the sliders only when value has changed, using updateSelectInput

```
 library(shiny)
digits=3
step <- .1^digits

# Dummy questions and alternatives
n <- 5

# Miscellaneous functions
updateprob <- function(oldprobs, new, i) {
  cat(oldprobs, new, i)
  if (new==oldprobs[i]) {
    cat("-\n")
    oldprobs 
  } else {
    newprobs <- rep(0,4)
    oldprobs <- oldprobs + 1e-6 # hack to avoid 0/0 = NaN in special cases
    newprobs[-i] <- round(oldprobs[-i]/sum(oldprobs[-i])*(1-new),digits=digits)
    newprobs[i] <- new
    cat("*\n")
    newprobs
  }
}
# wrapper function around sliderInput
probsliderInput <- function(inputId,value,submitted=FALSE) {
  if (!submitted)
    sliderInput(inputId=inputId,
                value=value,
                label=NULL,
                min=0,
                max=1,
                step=step,
                round=-digits,
                ticks=FALSE)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Initialize the quiz here, possibly permute the quiz
  prob <- reactiveValues(prob=matrix(rep(.25,4*n),n,4)) # current choice of probabilities
  question <- reactiveValues(i=1) # question number

  # Actions to take if pressing next and previous buttons
  observeEvent(input$nextquestion,{question$i <- min(question$i+1,n)}) 
  observeEvent(input$previousquestion,{question$i <- max(question$i-1,1)}) 

  # If any of the probability sliders change, then recalculate probabilities to satisfy sum to 1 constraint


  observeEvent(input$p1, 
               prob$prob[question$i,] <- updateprob(prob$prob[question$i,], input$p1, 1)
  )
  observeEvent(input$p2, 
               prob$prob[question$i,] <- updateprob(prob$prob[question$i,], input$p2, 2)
  )
  observeEvent(input$p3, 
               prob$prob[question$i,] <- updateprob(prob$prob[question$i,], input$p3, 3)
  )
  observeEvent(input$p4, 
               prob$prob[question$i,] <- updateprob(prob$prob[question$i,], input$p4, 4)
  ) 

  observeEvent(prob$prob  ,{  

      if (is.null(input$p1 ) || is.null(input$p2 ) ||  is.null(input$p3 ) ||  is.null(input$p4 ) ) { return(NULL)} 

      if ( prob$prob[question$i,1] != input$p1)  {    
          updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = 'p1', selected = prob$prob[question$i,1] )
      }  

       if ( prob$prob[question$i,2] != input$p2)  {   
         updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = 'p2', selected = prob$prob[question$i,2] )
       } 

       if ( prob$prob[question$i,3] != input$p3)  {  
         updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = 'p3', selected = prob$prob[question$i,3] )
       } 

       if ( prob$prob[question$i,4] != input$p4)  {  
         updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = 'p4', selected = prob$prob[question$i,4] )
       }
    })


  # If the probabilities change, update the sliders
  output$p1ui <- renderUI({
    isolate(probsliderInput("p1",prob$prob[question$i,1]))
  })
  output$p2ui <- renderUI({
   isolate( probsliderInput("p2",prob$prob[question$i,2]))
  })
  output$p3ui <- renderUI({
    isolate(probsliderInput("p3",prob$prob[question$i,3]))
  })
  output$p4ui <- renderUI({
    isolate(probsliderInput("p4",prob$prob[question$i,4]))
  })

  # Render the buttons sometimes greyed out
  output$previousbutton <- renderUI({
    actionButton("previousquestion",icon=icon("angle-left"),label="Previous",
                 style=if (question$i > 1) "color: #000" else "color: #aaa")
  })
  output$nextbutton <- renderUI({
    actionButton("nextquestion",icon=icon("angle-right"),label="Next",
                 style=if (question$i < n) "color: #000" else "color: #aaa")
  })

  # Current question number
  output$number <- renderText(paste("Question",question$i))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("previousbutton", inline = TRUE),
  uiOutput("nextbutton", inline = TRUE),
  textOutput("number"),
  uiOutput("p1ui"),
  uiOutput("p2ui"),
  uiOutput("p3ui"),
  uiOutput("p4ui")
)

shinyApp(ui=ui , server=server)
```