# Create interactive line with 3 colored segments?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggvis

Is it possible to create an interactive graph like the following with shiny + ggplot2, ggvis, or similar?

[image]

The idea is that if the user moves the 50% cutoff or the 75% cutoff the colors will adjust and the name of the segments will readjust to the middle of each segment.

Comment: Maybe relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952333/constrain-multiple-sliderinput-in-shiny-to-sum-to-100 or use range - http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/slider-bar-and-slider-range.html

Answer (score 2):

Since I am not really sure what you want here is a first guess for only 2 segments.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("cutoff",
                     "cutoff",
                     min = 0.01,
                     max = 1,
                     step = 0.01,
                     value = 0.5) 
      ),

      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("plot")
      )
   )
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

   output$plot <- renderPlot({
     df <- data.frame(x = seq(0.01, 1, 0.01), y = seq(0.01, 1, 0.01), 
                      group = c(rep("a", round(input$cutoff * 100)),
                                rep("b", round(((1-input$cutoff) * 100)))
                                )
                      )
     labelPos <- data.frame(pos = c(input$cutoff - input$cutoff/2, 
                                    (input$cutoff + (1 - input$cutoff)/2)
                                    ),
                            label = c("a", "b")
                            )

     ggplot()+ 
        geom_ribbon(data = df, aes(x=x, ymin = -0.2, ymax = 0.2, fill = group), show.legend = FALSE) + 
        geom_label(data = labelPos, aes(x = pos, y = 0.3, label = label)) +
        coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-1,1)) + 
        theme(line = element_blank(),
              text = element_blank(),
              line = element_blank(),
              title = element_blank()
              )

  })
})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps me think of a possible solution. What I want would have 3 segments, and the ability to click on the graph to move the 2 cutoff that define the 3 segments.

Comment: You mean you want the graph to behave like a slider? I do not think that there is a straight forward way (meaning I think you have to program it youself. Probaly with javascript but I am no expert).

Comment: Yes I have something like the range widget in mind but with 3 colors and some extra labels.