# Multiple constrained sliders in R ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a Shiny App with multiple sliders to control several constrained weights (i.e. they should add up to 1). My layman's attempt below 'works', but runs into an infinite loop when one of the parameters takes the extreme values (0 or 1).

I have tried with a reactive cache instead, but only the first slider to be modified would be 'observed' afterwards. Few random isolate calls took me nowhere. I still need to fully grasp how the update flow works. :/

I have seen an implementation for two complementary sliders, but failed to generalized it to many it seems.

Any help would be appreciated!
Best,
Martín

---

```
library(shiny)

states <- c('W1', 'W2', 'W3')
cache <- list()
hotkey <- ''
forget <- F

ui =pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Test 101"),
  sidebarPanel(
  sliderInput(inputId = "W1", label = "PAR1", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.2),
  sliderInput(inputId = "W2", label = "PAR2", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.2),
  sliderInput(inputId = "W3", label = "PAR3", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.6)
  ),
  mainPanel()
)

server = function(input, output, session){

  update_cache <- function(input){

    if(length(cache)==0){
      for(w in states)
      cache[[w]] <<- input[[w]]
    } else if(input[[hotkey]] < 1){

      for(w in states[!(states == hotkey)]){

        if(forget==T){
          newValue <- (1-input[[hotkey]])/(length(states)-1)
        } else{
          newValue <- cache[[w]] * (1 - input[[hotkey]])/(1-cache[[hotkey]])
        }
        cache[[w]] <<- ifelse(is.nan(newValue),0,newValue)
      }

      forget <<- F
      cache[[hotkey]] <<- input[[hotkey]]

    } else{
      for(w in states[!(states == hotkey)]){
        cache[[w]] <<- 0
      }
      forget <<- T
    }

  }

  # when water change, update air
  observeEvent(input$W1,  {
    hotkey <<- "W1"
    update_cache(input)

    for(w in states[!(states == hotkey)]){
      updateSliderInput(session = session, inputId = w, value = cache[[w]])
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$W2,  {
    hotkey <<- "W2"
    update_cache(input)
    for(w in states[!(states == hotkey)]){
      updateSliderInput(session = session, inputId = w, value = cache[[w]])
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$W3,  {
    hotkey <<- "W3"
    update_cache(input)
    for(w in states[!(states == hotkey)]){
      updateSliderInput(session = session, inputId = w, value = cache[[w]])
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution regarding the update logic:

```
library(shiny)

consideredDigits <- 3
stepWidth <- 1/10^(consideredDigits+1)

ui = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Test 101"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput(inputId = "W1", label = "PAR1", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.2, step = stepWidth),
    sliderInput(inputId = "W2", label = "PAR2", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.2, step = stepWidth),
    sliderInput(inputId = "W3", label = "PAR3", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.6, step = stepWidth),
    textOutput("sliderSum")
  ),
  mainPanel()
)

server = function(input, output, session){

  sliderInputIds <- paste0("W", 1:3)
  sliderState <- c(isolate(input$W1), isolate(input$W2), isolate(input$W3))
  names(sliderState) <- sliderInputIds

  observe({
    sliderDiff <- round(c(input$W1, input$W2, input$W3)-sliderState, digits = consideredDigits)
    if(any(sliderDiff != 0)){
      diffIdx <- which(sliderDiff != 0)
      if(length(diffIdx) == 1){
        diffID <- sliderInputIds[diffIdx]
        sliderState[-diffIdx] <<- sliderState[-diffIdx]-sliderDiff[diffIdx]/2
        if(any(sliderState[-diffIdx] < 0)){
          overflowIdx <- which(sliderState[-diffIdx] < 0)
          sliderState[-c(diffIdx, overflowIdx)] <<- sum(c(sliderState[-diffIdx]))
          sliderState[overflowIdx] <<- 0
        }
        for(sliderInputId in sliderInputIds[!sliderInputIds %in% diffID]){
          updateSliderInput(session, sliderInputId, value = sliderState[[sliderInputId]])
        }
        sliderState[diffIdx] <<- input[[diffID]]
      }
    }
    output$sliderSum <- renderText(paste("Sum:", sum(c(input$W1, input$W2, input$W3))))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The main problem is to take care of is the stepwidth of the sliders. If all sliders have the same stepwidth and you are trying to split the user-change of one slider and pass it to two others they won't be able to display that change once the user chooses to change only one step (would require updating the two dependant sliders with a half step) because it's below their resolution. Accodingly in my answer I'm only taking into account changes > stepwidth which causes rounding errors but works around the afore mentioned problem. You can reduce this error by increasing the considered digits.

Comment: Hi! unfortunately the logic is not quite right here either. Sometimes you run into total values greater than 1 (for the sum of the three slider values). 
I actually found a very similar question been asked here time ago : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952333/constrain-multiple-sliderinput-in-shiny-to-sum-to-100 . The original solution seems to work for me (although not using the dinamicUI approach I had in mind). It is in fact very similar to your code here (using 'observe({})' instead of my 'observeEvent({})' calls). Thanks a lot for your input @ismirsehregal, appreciate it.

Comment: Ah.. yes I see (it adds up in some cases), didn't spend enough time testing it seems. But good to see you found a solution. BR

Answer (score 0):

Making your hotkey a local in update_cache avoids the recursion:

```
library(shiny)

states <- c('W1', 'W2', 'W3')
cache <- list()
hotkey <- ''
forget <- F

ui =pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Test 101"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput(inputId = "W1", label = "PAR1", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.2),
    sliderInput(inputId = "W2", label = "PAR2", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.2),
    sliderInput(inputId = "W3", label = "PAR3", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.6)
  ),
  mainPanel()
)

server = function(input, output, session){

  update_cache <- function(input, hotkey){

    if(length(cache)==0){
      for(w in states)
        cache[[w]] <<- input[[w]]
    } else if(input[[hotkey]] < 1){

      for(w in states[!(states == hotkey)]){

        if(forget==T){
          newValue <- (1-input[[hotkey]])/(length(states)-1)
        } else{
          newValue <- cache[[w]] * (1 - input[[hotkey]])/(1-cache[[hotkey]])
        }
        cache[[w]] <<- ifelse(is.nan(newValue),0,newValue)
      }

      forget <<- F
      cache[[hotkey]] <<- input[[hotkey]]

    } else{
      for(w in states[!(states == hotkey)]){
        cache[[w]] <<- 0
      }
      forget <<- T
    }

  }

  # when water change, update air
  observeEvent(input$W1,  {
    update_cache(input, "W1")
    for(w in states[!(states == hotkey)]){
      updateSliderInput(session = session, inputId = w, value = cache[[w]])
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$W2,  {
    update_cache(input, "W2")
    for(w in states[!(states == hotkey)]){
      updateSliderInput(session = session, inputId = w, value = cache[[w]])
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$W3,  {
    update_cache(input, "W3")
    for(w in states[!(states == hotkey)]){
      updateSliderInput(session = session, inputId = w, value = cache[[w]])
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @ismirsehregal !  Although the long-standing recursion is gone with your suggestion, it is still not working as intended. Whenever any variable takes a extreme value (0 or 1), two of them fluctuate down/up to 0.5 and stay there after a brief updating loop. Need to revise the update/forget logic it seems...

Comment: I didn't spend any time looking at that logic, because I don't know what you intended.

Comment: I just meant to have three complementary sliders (i.e. that the three values always add up to 1)

Comment: Please check my second answer.